# Xamarin Studio Build Error File 'Windows.Props' not found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, mobile-development

I just downloaded Xamarin studio but when I try to compile the code it gets this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\
Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(9,9): 
Error APPX1639: File 'Windows.props' not found. 
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=1.0&plcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=PlatformMultiTargeting&o1=
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Portable\v12.0&o2=Portable for more information. (APPX1639) (ToDo)
```

I already installed the sdk for Windows 10, and tried to repair the app but nothing happened.

Comment: What kind of code/project are you trying to build?

Comment: A simple todo app. though I also tried a simple HelloWorld, it still says the error.

I tried running the same thing in VS 2015 and it worked fine the error is just in Xamarin Studio